# MatPlotLib plots overlaying on one-another

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot multiple separate figures and put them into a pdf (using FPDF if relevant). However, I'm facing an issue when it comes to generating these figures. I've been trying to plot them all and save them individually, however, the result ends up being like this:
[image: Asset Chart plot (overlaying table plots)]

However, my first plot seems to be completely fine:
[image: Note that this is all fake data that I was testing with - nothing confidential]

Here's my current code:

```
pltAssets = plt

pltAssets.axis('off')
pltAssets.axis('tight')
pltAssets.table(cellText=dfAssets.values, colLabels=dfAssets.columns, loc='center')
pltAssets.savefig('FILES/assets.png', dpi=300)
pltAssets.close()

labels = "Debt", "Equity", "Real Estate", "Cash", "Misc"
values = [10000, 10700, 1402, 101412, 31214]
colors = ["#ff6384", "#36a2eb","#ff9f40","#9966ff", "#36a832"]
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, colors=colors)
plt.title("Asset Allocation")
plt.savefig('FILES/asset_chart.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
plt.close()

#Note that this is only a section of the code, however, the rest is just a
#variation of how I've done it here and is essentially irrelevent
```

Thank you so much for your help.
[Note that this is all fake data that I was testing with - nothing confidential]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact reason why this error occurred is still unknown to me, however, my solution is quite simple:

Instead of creating more instances of plt (ie how I created pltAssets), just use plt normally, however, use plt.show() and plt.close() to get rid of the previous chart.

Here's my current code (not for the same data as in the example, but concept is the same):

```
        plt.title("Fund/Stock Value")
        plt.xlabel("Month")
        plt.ylabel("Value")
        plt.savefig('FILES/value_chart.png', dpi=300)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
    
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.axis('tight')
        plt.title("Investments")
        plt.table(cellText=dfInvest.values, colLabels=dfInvest.columns, loc='center')
        plt.savefig('FILES/invest_table.png', dpi=300)
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
```